# Django Modelform user issues

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model form to list an item and I am trying to get the form to fill in the user id from the user that is submitting the form. Currently, the form is submitted successfully but it always uses the first user in the database's id for every item.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField( primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False )
creator = models.ForeignKey( get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=2)
item_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places=2)
description = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_and_rename , max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
image_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
image_3= models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
image_4= models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
image_5= models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[ MaxValueValidator(100),MinValueValidator(1)])
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.item_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("item_detail_view", args=[str(self.id)])
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from .models import Item

class List_Item_Form(ModelForm):
forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.filter(user=user))
   
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
class AddListing( generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'store/add_listing.html'
    fields = ('item_name','price','description','main_image','quantity')
    model = Item
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: So what you are expecting? What do you exactly want?

Comment: Basically the user is listing an item and I want that item to be associated with that user. So the foreign key in the item model would be the users ID that listed the item.

Comment: Op, reviewer: please, do not accept the edit suggestion. The identation should not be corrected

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `function` based view too because there we get `current` user more easily.

Try this:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Item(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    main_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=path_and_rename, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    image_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
    image_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
    image_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
    image_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/', blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from home.models import Item
@admin.register(Item)
class ItemRegister(admin.ModelAdmin):
    lis_display = ['id', 'creator', 'item_name', 'price', 'description']
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.list, name='home'),
    path('success/', views.success, name='success')
]
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from .models import Item


class ListItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['item_name', 'price', 'main_image'
                  'description', 'quantity']
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Item
from .forms import ListItemForm


def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            itemName = form.cleaned_data['item_name']
            price = form.cleaned_data['price']
            desc = form.cleaned_data['description']
            quan = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            main_img = form.cleaned_data['main_image']
            current_user = request.user
            model_instance = Item(creator=current_user, item_name=itemName, price=price,
                                  description=desc, quantity=quan, main_image=main_img)
            model_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
    else:
        form = ListItemForm()
    return render(request, 'store/add_listing.html', {'form': form})


def success(request):
    return render(request, 'store/success.html')
```

Rest of the `fields` of models you can customize very easily in the `view`.

Comment: thank you for your responce. I Have gotten close but I'm getting the following error

Comment: What's error you got?

Comment: So I am using allauth and am getting Exception Type: AttributeError at /store/add_listing/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'CustomUser'           I replaced current_user = request.user with current_user = request.CustomUser #current_user =  user.objects.filter(current_user) # current_user = get_user_model() all of which did work or gave me Cannot assign "<class 'accounts.models.CustomUser'>": "Item.creator" must be a "CustomUser" instance.

Comment: Can you update your question with full traceback? It seems you have done much more things in your project.

Comment: I created a new question =/. Not sure if creating a new question is best practice. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477021/allauth-get-user-model-customuser-issue

Comment: No it's not if it is existing question you can update it.